# can not insert data to the db php/msql

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a chatting system where one can send a message which will be store in the db which can be retrieved to be displayed in the inbox, now when i am trying to save the message i cannot insert the info to the db. please help

CODE:

```
include("inc/header.inc.php");

if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);

    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
        //check user exists
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($check) === 1) {
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['username'];

            //Check user isn't sending themself a private message
            if ($username != $user) {
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $msg_title = strip_tags($_POST['msg_title']);
                    $msg_body = strip_tags($_POST['msg_body']);
                    $date = date("Y-m-d");
                    $opened = "no";
                    $deleted = "no";

                    if ($msg_title == "Enter the message title here ...") {
                        echo "Please give your message a title.";
                    }
                    else if (strlen($msg_title) < 3) {
                        echo "Your message title cannot be less than 3 characters in length!";
                    }
                    else if ($msg_body == "Enter the message you wish to send ...") {
                        echo "Please write a message.";
                    }
                    else if (strlen($msg_body) < 3) {
                        echo "Your message cannot be less than 3 characters in length!";
                    }
                    else {
                        $send_msg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pvt_messages (id, user_from, user_to, msg_body, date, opened) VALUES ('','$user','$username','$msg_title','$msg_body','$date','$opened','$deleted')");
                        echo "Your message has been sent!";
                    }
                }
                echo "
                    <form action='send_msg.php?u=$username' method='POST'>
                    <h2>Compose a Message to $username</h2>
                    <input type='text' name='msg_title' size='30' onClick=\"value=''\" value='Enter the message title here ...'><p />
                    <textarea cols='50' rows='12' name='msg_body' style='margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 305px;'>Enter the message you wish to send ...</textarea><p />
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Send Message'>
                    </form>
                ";

            }
            else {
                header("Location: $user");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what maybe the problem?

Comment: You never set `$user`. Also you don't need `$username != $user` if you get a result you know the username is equal to the submitted username.

Comment: @chris85 so many "maybes" below. *Facepalm*.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Answer (score 0):

U insert '' into "id" column - isn't this wrong ? Use maybe try{} catch{} to check if is some error. And dont use strip_tags (rather filter_var or htmlentities). Read about Sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

i found my mistake, i had more values to be inserted than the actual columns in the db, so i removed the columns which are not present in the VALUES () section.

thanks for your options to, will try them out.

Answer (score -1):

Can be wrong, but shouldn't you use "mysql_query("INSERT..." instead "$send_msg = mysql_query("INSERT..."

Comment: That doesn't matter, variable assignments don't need to be accessed later on, unless using a conditional statement. Guesses are best left to be in comments. Please wait till you can and gain enough rep for it.

Comment: flag declined. *Major facepalm*.